# NotFittedError says this StandardScaler instance is not fitted yet while using inverse_transform()

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, feature-scaling, svr

I have a dataset and i have used **Support Vector Regression**.So i needed to use **StandardScaler** module from **sklearn.preprocessing** fro Feature Scaling.
After training my model when i came to predict it was giving a prediction which was Feature scaled.That's why i used **inverse_transform**from **StandardScaler()** and getting a error saying

> NotFittedError: This StandardScaler instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator.

I have tried several solutions but it's getting the same error. What can i do now?

[My dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rPPtWJxNGk5Z199kYeLLUYbUDaLsnPhk/view?usp=sharing)

Here is my code :

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sbn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_csv('Position_Salaries.csv')
x = df.iloc[:,1:2].values
y = df.iloc[:,2:].values
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
x = StandardScaler().fit_transform(x)
y = StandardScaler().fit_transform(y)
from sklearn.svm import SVR
regressor = SVR(kernel = 'rbf')
regressor.fit(x,y)
y_pred = regressor.predict(StandardScaler().fit_transform(np.array([[6.5]])))
y_pred = StandardScaler().inverse_transform(y_pred)
```

Error log : [image: Error Log]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to scale just one record, so you need to save the Scaler fitted on the training data

```py
sc = StandardScaler()
sc.fit(x)
x = sc.transform(x)
y_pred = regressor.predict(sc.transform(np.array([[6.5]]))
```

Make sure that the number of features is same in both cases otherwise you will get other errors.

#### A Working example

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data 

sc = StandardScaler()
sc.fit(X)
x = sc.transform(X)
#On new data, though data count is one but Features count is still Four
sc.transform(np.array([[6.5, 1.5, 2.5, 6.5]]))
```

Comment: thanks @10xAI but it would be more easy if you have given a example where there are two variables (x,y) though i get get.